# Vuetify Datatables Cells Text not vertically center aligned

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js

I am trying vuetify on laravel vue application, everything seems okay except datatables styles, padding of cells is not center aligned vertically. Here is screenshot [image]

The same code works fine in codepen, here is the link

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'left',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Actions', value: 'name', sortable: false }
    ],
    desserts: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      name: '',
      calories: 0,
      fat: 0,
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0
    },
    defaultItem: {
      name: '',
      calories: 0,
      fat: 0,
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0
    }
  }),

  computed: {
    formTitle () {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
    }
  },

  watch: {
    dialog (val) {
      val || this.close()
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.initialize()
  },

  methods: {
    initialize () {
      this.desserts = [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7
        }
      ]
    },

    editItem (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialog = true
    },

    deleteItem (item) {
      const index = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
      confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.desserts.splice(index, 1)
    },

    close () {
      this.dialog = false
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
        this.editedIndex = -1
      }, 300)
    },

    save () {
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(this.desserts[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
      } else {
        this.desserts.push(this.editedItem)
      }
      this.close()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <v-btn slot="activator" color="primary" dark class="mb-2">New Item</v-btn>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.calories" label="Calories"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fat" label="Fat (g)"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.carbs" label="Carbs (g)"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.protein" label="Protein (g)"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="close">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click.native="save">Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
            <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="teal">edit</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
              <v-icon color="pink">delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </td>
        </template>
        <template slot="no-data">
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEZjrV?&editors=101

The issue seems to be a conflict with bootstrap, is there a way to fix this? The same with problem also bulma

Comment: Maybe some of your CSS overrides the default CSS, add CSS:-    td { vertical-align: middle; }

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set your table with center align , change this on your td class `class="text-xs-right"`with `class="text-xs-center"`. and add some props in your headers with `align: 'center'`